# How do i get an i with circumflex and point in text mode?

Tags: accents

I am using bold upright tensor indices, which I include in a math environment via `\textbf{}`. I now want a little hat on these indices, which include the letter `i`. However, when I write `\textbf{\^{i}}` I get an `i` where the point has been replaced by the circumflex. This does not happen for `j`, there I get a point and a circumflex. 
I am not even sure if this is standard behaviour or if some package does this so that French words with accents look right.
I want the point and the circumflex for the `i`. Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: `\hat{\mathbf{i}}`; don't use `\textbf` for this purpose in math mode.

Comment: Typesetting `\^{i}` without a dot in text mode is intentional, because that is what you want for most western-alphabet languages that use accents. In cases where an accented i or j does get dot by default but you don't want one, the macros `\i` and `\j` give dotless letters.

Answer (score 2):

I see quite often `\textbf` used in math mode. It isn't correct for a very important reason: its realization depends on the font current *outside* math mode, so it could be rendered as “bold italic” if appearing in a theorem statement.

The correct way to obtain “upright boldface” for a math letter is

```
\mathbf{<letter>}
```

Also accents should be the math ones, rather than the text accents.

So your symbol should be typed in as

```
\hat{\mathbf{i}}
```

(put a math accent hat above a boldface i). Notwithstanding that `\mathbf{\hat{i}}` produces the same result, the suggested syntax is more adherent to the semantic of the symbol.

There are legitimate usages of `\textbf` in math mode, but only for *words* that happen to be part of a formula and need to be typeset boldface (I'd say it should be very rare).